# How to fix "webpack Dev Server Invalid Options" in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

I am using `@vue/cli v3.7.0` and I created a project by `vue create myapp` with Babel + Router + node-sass and my project got installed successfully

But when I ran npm run serve (in the project directory) I got following error:

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  ValidationError: webpack Dev Server Invalid Options

options.clientLogLevel should be {String} and equal to one of the allowed values

 [ 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'debug', 'trace', 'silent' ]

 (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverclientloglevel)

ValidationError: webpack Dev Server Invalid Options

options.clientLogLevel should be {String} and equal to one of the allowed values

 [ 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'debug', 'trace', 'silent' ]

 (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverclientloglevel)

    at validateOptions (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:32:11)
    at new Server (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:71:5)
    at serve (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:138:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-17T19_40_14_984Z-debug.log
```

I tried `npm cache clean -f`, reinstallation of VueJS, recreation of project but nothing worked :(

I expect my `npm run serve` work!

Comment: This error seem pretty clear, your `options.clientLogLevel` value seems wrong

Comment: How can I fix this error? How can I change that value in webpack configuration as in my project I don't have any `webpack.config.js`. Webpack stuff is managed by VueJS for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yea this issue just popped up in the last few hours in `@vue/cli`. I had the same thing in a fresh project. To fix it try this:

1. Create a file in the root of your project called `vue.config.js` if you don't already have that file.
2. Add this to that file:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'info'
  }
};
```

Then re-run your project. Something happened last night where the `clientLogLevel` value that comes preset became incorrect.

Here's a thread talking about this issue: [GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4017).

Comment: Got the same error today when I upgrade Vue CLI service in an existing project and after creating a hello word example. This change does idd make the webpack config valid again. Seems like a mistake in the default config.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea why you're getting that error but here is how you'd configure that option:

1.
Create `vue.config.js` in your root directory

2.
Enter the following into it:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'debug'
  }
}
```

3.
Rerun `npm run serve`

You can read more about configuring the dev server [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove node_modules folder and npm install agani

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs are a little confusing when using `@vue/cli-service`, since it essentially wraps webpack.

[Here is a link to the solution](
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration)

Best thing to do is update your `vue.config.js` with something like

```
configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      clientLogLevel: `silent`,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `webpack-dev-server@3.4.0` broke something. I reverted it to `3.3.1` and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I edited

> node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js

so that line 139 says:

> clientLogLevel: 'warn'

instead of

> clientLogLevel: 'none'

(Edit - though I'm working with the hello-world app)

Answer (score 0):

webpack-dev-server has been released as v3.4.1 for hotfix.
Please update.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v3.4.1